# ExtJs4 - equivalent to ExtJs3 'tabPanel.getTabEl()' method?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

What is the equivalent to ExtJs3 method `tabpanel.getTabEl()` in ExtJs4?

Answer (score 3):

In Ext4 the tabs themselves are just fancy buttons!

So:

```
var btn = tabPanel.getComponent('foo').tab;
// console.log(btn, btn.el);
```

Comment: I have same doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)